# Bot Framework Emulator and Cortana userinfo

Tags: botframework, cortana-skills-kit

I'm trying to create a location aware Cortana skill and for that I need a bot that works with this.

However when trying to develop this bot with the bot framework emulator I'm having issues debugging the location aware part as I'm not getting the [userinfo entity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/tutorials/bot-skills/bot-entity-channel-data#User-Profile-Information) that Cortana should provide. Is this possible at all with the emulator as it does not seem possible to have Cortana connect to my Visual Studio debug session.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the emulator does not provide any options to pass along entities and channelData with request such as user profile and contextual information as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/testing/testing-and-debugging#bot-framework-skills).

You should be able to debug your `Cortana` Skill by using `ngrok` to create a tunneling to your localhost bot. After that, you should update the url of your bot in the BotFramework Dev portal.

Also, have in mind that for the skill to sync with `Cortana`, the test device must be logged in with the same Microsoft account used to create the skill (see [Set up your Cortana skills development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cortana/tutorials/setup-dev-env)

Answer (score 0):

As Ezequiel wrote, you have to debug your skill in Cortana and/or from your phone.

List of step are:

1. create your bot
2. configure it and obtain app id/password
3. config the permissions and user info you want to access
4. then enable the Cortana channel from the skill dashboard
5. provided all the relevant required info
6. you're good to go (if I didn't forget anything)

You log in with Cortana using the same email address you used to register your bot, at this point you're able to invoke your bot/skill using the invocation name. From your phone (I tried only on Android) you can do it just typing in Cortana (no need for voice).

Please, bear in mind when creating your **bot** that ***if you use a WORK account you will not be able to add Cortana as a channel to your bot***; therefore, no Cortana Skill. Microsoft doesn't support it yet.